# Key Press to inactive window

Tags: c, winapi

I'm trying to make a program that sends key presses to an inactive window, I'm using "SendMessageCallback()" but it isn't giving an error, or sending the key press.

```
typedef enum {false,true} bool;
bool KeyDown(HWND hWnd, WORD dKey){
if(!SendMessageCallback(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, 0, dKey, (SENDASYNCPROC)NULL, (ULONG_PTR)NULL))
    return false;
return true;
}

bool KeyUp(HWND hWnd, WORD uKey){
if(!SendMessageCallback(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, 0, uKey, (SENDASYNCPROC)NULL, (ULONG_PTR)NULL))
    return false;
return true;
}
```

then, I simply call it like this:

```
HWND FOO = FindWindow("FOO", NULL );
                if( FOO == NULL )
                    MessageBox(NULL, "FOO Not Found", "ERROR", MB_OK);
            if (!KeyDown(FOO, VK_SPACE))
                MessageBox(NULL, "KeyDown failed to execute!", "ERROR", MB_OK);
            if (!KeyUp(FOO, VK_SPACE))
                MessageBox(NULL, "KeyUp failed to execute!", "ERROR", MB_OK);
```

I substituted What the real HWND is for FOO, If more information is needed please tell me.
The problem is it doesn't send the key press or show a message box.

Edit: I tried adding a delay between pressing the key down and releasing it and that didn't solve it.

Comment: I've added the winapi tag, since this is important information (i.e. you could have been talking about QT or X).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "substituted What the real HWND is for FOO" (i.e. show us exactly the code you are compiling)? The problem may be there.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I did, it is here: http://pastebin.com/C8iuEpQc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing anything about the window you are working with, I can only surmise that it is not coded to process keystrokes in its WndProc.  You can use Spy++ or similar tool to verify that the messages are actually being sent, but that is no guarantee that they will be processed. You cannot send keystrokes to arbitrary windows that are not expecting them.  And BTW, keystroke messages are typically posted to a window's message queue, not sent directly to the window's WndProc, so try using `PostMessage()` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I guess it doesn't really matter if i post everything. L
Here is my whole code:
http://pastebin.com/C8iuEpQc
I tried subbing SendMessageCallback() with PostMessage() and the keystrokes were still ignored.

I'm sending them to Spotify, it's a music client.

Comment: @Lygophobia I agree with this solution. Many things can go wrong in this case. The inactive window may switch into a completely different processing logic in response to `WM_ACTIVATE` or `WN_ACTIVATEAPP` when it goes inactive. Not to mention that the window may completely ignore window messages if it is a game and uses for example DirectInput.

Comment: @pasztorpisti I tried PostMessage() it still didn't send th keystrokes. unless i am using the function wrong.

bool KeyDown(HWND hWnd, WORD dKey){
    if(!PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, 0, dKey))
        return false;
    return true;
}

Comment: @Lygophobia Unfortunately noone will be able to tell you whats wrong. You have to dig into the other application if you want to hack it around this way.

Comment: @pasztorpisti thank you for your honesty, i'll try to figure something out then.